# New commands for the equation environment

Tags: macros, equations, brackets

I'm trying to define a bra-ket command so that I can easily build things like:

```
\langle e^+ | \gamma^\mu | e^-\rangle
```

At the moment I have this:

```
\newcommand{\brak}[3]{
\langle #1 \| \gamma^{#2} \| #3 \rangle
}
```

but, when I have `\brak(e^+, \mu, e^-)` in an equation I get:

```
⟨e−,μ,e+∥γ
∥equation⟩
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is the [`braket`](http://ctan.org/pkg/braket) package which might save you some trouble

Comment: you could also use the `physics`-package which has `\bra{}` and `\ket{}` commands (and other useful stuff).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use

```
\brak{e^+}{\mu}{e^-}
```

There're 3 different arguments, you can't separate them by commas.

Comment: Ah great - my head was still in c++ mode!

Answer (score 5):

Just to show a version with build in scaling:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\brak[3]\langle\rangle{%
#1 \delimsize\vert #2 \delimsize\vert #3}
\begin{document}

\[
\brak{e^+}{\mu}{e^-}
\qquad
\brak*{e^+}{\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}}}{e^-}
\qquad
\brak[\Big]{e^+}{\sum_i \mu_i }{e^-}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]